# Add class to the label for radio button in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am facing a problem in adding a class to the radio button label in cakephp 3.

My code is :

```
<?= $this->Form->input('enroll',[
    'type'=>'radio',
    'options'=>[
        [
            'value'=>'1',
            'text'=>'Yes',
            'class'=>'checkbox'
        ],
        [
            'value'=>'0',
            'text'=>'No',
            'class'=>'checkbox'
        ]
    ],
    'label'=>false
  ])
?>
```

This is generating following Html:

```
<div class="input radio">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="enroll">
    <label for="enroll-1">
        <input type="radio" id="enroll-1" class="checkbox" value="1" name="enroll">
        Yes
    </label>
    <label for="enroll-0">
        <input type="radio" id="enroll-0" class="checkbox" value="0" name="enroll">
        No
    </label>
</div>
```

What I Want is:

```
<div class="input radio">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="enroll">
<label for="enroll-1" class="checked-input">
    <input type="radio" id="enroll-1" class="checkbox" value="1" name="enroll">
    Yes
</label>
<label for="enroll-0" class="checked-input">
    <input type="radio" id="enroll-0" class="checkbox" value="0" name="enroll">
    No
</label>
```

I want a class to be added to the `<label for=''>`.

What I Tried was:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('enroll',[
    'type'=>'radio',
    'templates'=>[
        'label'=>'<label {{attrs}} class="checked-input">{{text}}</label>',
        'radioWrapper'=>'{{label}}'
    'options'=>[
        [
            'value'=>'1',
            'text'=>'Yes',
            'class'=>'checkbox'
        ],
        [
            'value'=>'0',
            'text'=>'No',
            'class'=>'checkbox'
        ]
    ],
    'label'=>false
  ])
?>
```

But I am not able to do that. I have tried lots of other things but they aren't working either. Please help.

Comment: `{$this->Form->radio('enroll', $options, ['label' => ['class' => 'checked-input']])}` does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply you have to modify `nestingLabel` template instead of `label` template

```
'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}} class="checked-input">{{input}}{{text}}</label>'
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. @arilia

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('reason', array('options' => $reasons, 'type' => 'radio', 'label' => false, 'required' => true,
                                'templates' => [
                                    'nestingLabel' => '{{hidden}}<label{{attrs}} class="checked-input">{{input}}{{text}}</label>',
                                ]
                            ));

Not working, my I know why please?

Answer (score 0):

This is also working.

```
<?= $this->Form->input('current_password', [
                'type' => 'password',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => ['class' => 'hello']]);
        ?>
```